# Lyx - Add appendix after bibliography

Tags: lyx

How can I insert Appendix after Bibliography ?
If I put the cursor after the last character of the bibliography, then the last line of the bibliography is inside the appendix. If I click return after the last character of the bibliography, then insert the appendix, a new key appears in the appendix, and if I remove it, the appendix disappears.

Thanks,

Edit:
I click on alt+Enter after the bibliography to close it. Then I insert a clear page, insert a new chapter, and start the appendix.
Everything looks OK in Lyx, but in the PDF, I have the title "Bibliography" on top of the pages of the Appendix.
My document class is "book(more font sizes)".

Edit 2: I am using the following preamble (if it has anything to see with the problem):

```
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{Tableau}
}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.85}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstset{%
     language=Matlab,%
     float=hbp,%
     basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
     identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},%
     keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},%
     stringstyle=\color{colString},%
     commentstyle=\itshape\color{colComments},%
     columns=fixed,
     tabsize=4,%
     frame=single,%
     framerule=1pt,
     extendedchars=true,%
     showspaces=false,%
     showstringspaces=false,%
     numbers=left,%
     numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,%
     numbersep=1em,%
     breaklines=true,%
     breakindent=10pt,%
     backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},%
     breakautoindent=true,%
     captionpos=t,%
     xleftmargin=1em,%
     xrightmargin=\fboxsep%
}
```

Comment: No problem here. Do you create your bibliography using `Insert | List / TOC | BibTex Bibliography` and, after that, create the appendix with `Document | Start Appendix Here`? That works perfectly well for me! (LyX 2.0.6 on Linux)

Comment: Start the new chapter *after* the start of the appendix.

Comment: Same result, Bibliography still appears on top of pdf.

Comment: That part of the preamble is irrelevant. You do mean that *Bibliography* is written in the header right, similar to the chapter name in earlier chapters? You can drop the `\clearpage` by the way, that was just a mistake on my part. If I do what I said, i.e. 1: Alt+enter,  2: Document -> start appendix, 3: Add a new chapter, as seen in http://imgur.com/mTscdRT, the header on the second page of Appendix A has the name of that appendix in the header.

Comment: It works if I select Chapter, but not if I select Chapter*, and I would like to display just Appendice and not Appendice A.

Comment: Can you ask a new question about that, it really is a completely different issue than your original question, and I don't have a solution at the moment.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create bibliography by selecting *Bibliography* from the drop-down menu, and writing the bibliography manually, you can 'close' this by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the cursor is at the end of the last entry. Then you can type stuff after the bibliography, and start the appendices.

Comment: I still have a problem: now the title Bibliography appears in top of the pages of the Appendix. –

Comment: @Gilbert Try Insert --> Formatting --> Clear page before you start the appendix.

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: @Gilbert Damn, sorry, I wasn't thinking properly, so that last comment of mine was wrong. You're using a Book class right? Add a chapter at the start of the appendix.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: @Gilbert Ok, I'm not sure. Can you ask a new question, describing in detail what you do?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, rather than alt-enter use ctrl-enter. If you have Lyx's "source pane" open, you can see this finally moves the cursor beyond the end of the'bibliography section. (Alt-enter just adds extra lines inside of the final bib'item, which isn't helpful.)

This will make you free to "start appendix here" (lyx document menu) and create the chapters of the appendix. Then you can move on to grappling with the format of their headings and table of contents entries!

Answer (score -1):

After your bibliography insert a blank line as Chapter and write your chapter title. Then use de menu entry Document->Start appendix and that will make the trick. In your TOC the chapters in the appendix box will appear after the bibliography and using letters instead of numbers.